# Why is meteor.js synchronous?

Tags: node.js, meteor, node-fibers

Doesn't code take an efficiency hit by being synchronous?  Why is coding synchronously a win?
I found these two links in doing some research: http://bjouhier.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/fibers-and-threads-in-node-js-what-for/, https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs/

If the goal is to prevent spaghetti code, then clearly you can have asynchronous code, with streamline.js for example, that isn't a callback pyramid, right?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to distinguish two things here:

- Synchronous functions like node's `fs.readFileSync`, `fs.statSync`, etc. All these functions have a `Sync` in their names (*). These functions are truly *synchronous* and *blocking*. If you call them, you block the event loop and you kill node's performance. You should only use these functions in your server's initialization script (or in command-line scripts).
- Libraries and tools like *fibers* or *streamline.js*. These solutions allow you to write your code in *sync-style* but the code that you write with them will still execute *asynchronously*. They do *not* block the event loop.

(*) `require` is also blocking.

Meteor uses *fibers*. Its code is written in sync-style but it is non-blocking.

The win is not on the performance side (these solutions have their own overhead so they may be marginally slower but they can also do better than raw callbacks on specific code patterns like caching). The win, and the reason why these solutions have been developed, is on the usability side: they let you write your code in sync-style, even if you are calling asynchronous functions.

**Jan 25 2017 edit**: I created 3 gists to illustrate non-blocking fibers: 
[fibers-does-not-block.js](https://gist.github.com/bjouhier/7d660269b6fae13b7e33081d391c665d), [fibers-sleep-sequential.js](https://gist.github.com/bjouhier/ab384311dc10d67e2599b367eecc3fa2), [fibers-sleep-parallel.js](https://gist.github.com/bjouhier/b26e69ff5ecec58dd8d6e62c5d3ebcc4)

Comment: "They do not block the event loop." The statement is misleading as fibers have to block the event loop in critical sections. It is up to developer to decide what  the critical sections are and use fibers appropriately.

Comment: @ashim. This is wrong: fibers are non-preemptive; context switches between fibers are implemented by libcoro and are completely decoupled from the event loop.

Comment: I am confused. If I put i/o operations inside a fiber, between fiber.run() fiber.yield() commands, then the rest of the program is going to wait until that section of code executed. How it is not blocking? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Your fiber will start the I/O operation and then call `Fiber.yield()`. This yield will save the context and transfer control to the main loop  which will process all the callbacks, as usual. When your I/O callback eventually fires, it will call `fiber.run()` from the main loop to resume execution of your fiber where it yielded before. The event loop is never blocked; it runs while your code _appears_ to block on `Fiber.yield()`. Same thing with `async/await`: main loop runs everywhere your code _awaits_.

Comment: I created a small gist to illustrate callbacks firing during `Fiber.yield()`: https://gist.github.com/bjouhier/7d660269b6fae13b7e33081d391c665d

Comment: That is a great example! You might consider adding it to your original answer. Other people will benefit too. One more question though. What if we have 2 update methods to a mongodb (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/). If we do fiber.run() only in the callback, then we block execution only after the db has been modified. Such situation is a race condition. How can fibers help here?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "race condition". I've created 2 more gists: one for sequential execution: https://gist.github.com/bjouhier/ab384311dc10d67e2599b367eecc3fa2  and one for parallel execution: https://gist.github.com/bjouhier/b26e69ff5ecec58dd8d6e62c5d3ebcc4. Notice how the "tick" keeps running in both cases. If you have several fibers that access a shared resource, you may need a synchronization primitive. For this I'm using a small "funnel" utility. See https://github.com/Sage/f-promise/blob/master/README.md#funnel

Answer (score 3):

The code is not "synchronous" when using something like `streamlinejs`. The actual code will **still run asynchronously**. It's not very pretty to write lots of anonymous callback functions, thats where these things helps.